# oauth 1.0 for wp api and ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, oauth, ionic-framework

For the Oauth 1.0 , i am already get the access token from the server.

access_token is 'Kdsfauidf343daasdfasewr', but on ionic framework, how do i use access_token?

i try following code on ionic framework

```
$http({method: 'GET', headers: {'Authorization' : 'Token Kdsfauidf343daasdfasewr '}
})
```

it return 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: can you got solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Only set an access token is not sufficient. You'll have to use a signature for each request to the WP API. Especially you can read this part of WP API Oauth documentation on [github](https://github.com/WP-API/OAuth1/blob/master/docs/basics/Signing.md):

Otherwise a more detailed article I found on Nic Raboy's [blog](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/11/understanding-request-signing-oauth-1-0a-providers/):